# flash sound malfunction

Tags: audio, flash, flash-cs3, flash-cs6

**Problem summary:**

A sound (stream) placed inside a movie clip that is within another movie clip will start playing continuously when I use the play control to jump around on the main timeline.

**Details:**

I am using Flash CS3 but the same issue occurs with CS6. I've spent quite a bit time to search/research for the issue but didn't find a solution. To demonstrate the problem, I've reduced the flash movie to a very simple structure.

One the main timeline:

- The first frame has a movie clip (Game MC) and a stop action.
- Following the first frame, there are several frames, mostly empty except some text.
- The last frame has a stop action.

On the Game MC timeline:

- There is only one frame. On that frame, there is a movie clip (Card MC), and the stop action.

On the Card MC timeline:

- It starts with 3 blank frames and a stop action.
- Starting at frame 4, a sound (.wav format) is placed and is set to be "stream."
- At the end of this timeline, there is a stop action.

From Flash CS3, I press Ctrl+Enter to test the movie. The movie stops on frame 1 of the main timeline with the card showing, no sound, as expected. Now I use "." to move the play head forward one frame at a time. No problem. I see the frames after the first frame. Still no sound, as expected. So far so good.

**The problem starts** when I use "," to move the play head backward, the sound in the Card MC starts to play, regardless where the play head is, even when the Game MC (thence the Card MC) is not on the stage. Worse, each press of "," will trigger another start of the same sound overlapping with the previous one. And the sound would continue in loops until I close the swf.

**However,** the problem will not occur if I place the Card MC directly on the main timeline. It only occurs when it is inside another movie clip (Game MC).

I need to solve this problem because the full version of the flash card game is to be placed in an HTML page with a javascript based play control, which allows the viewer to jump around in the swf timeline.

The fla file is at: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_5mgotjr4l5RDZaOGxFeFFWN1U/edit?pli=1

Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

Keith

Comment: Tried changing the sound to "event" or "start". It made no difference. Tested with trace statements on the timeline of Card MC and none was executed when the sound went berserk.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to be a bug in Flash indeed and was told that it would not be in the next version of Flash. The workaround is to use the Sound class to load and play the sound.